# Git merge for 2 branches

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-branch, merge-conflict-resolution

There is a branch A. I branched from branch A so I have a branch B. I branched from branch B so I have a branch C.

In a while the file `file1.js` was changed in A, `file1.js` (not `file2.js`, but the same `file1.js`) in B and `file3.js` in C.
Then B was merged into A with resolving conflicts because of `file1.js`.

If I merge C into A after B was merged into A, will I get any conflicts?
I expect the answer is no, however I'm still curious if I have to resolve `file1.js` conflicts in any way when merging C into A or if I expect to get any difficuilties with merging.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you will not get any conflicts... :|

Comment: If `file1.js` was changed in branch B before you created branch C from branch B than there will probably be a conflict. It's the exact same situation you had when you tried to merge branch B into A. If you changed `file1.js` in branch B after you've created branch C there won't be a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be a conflict. Merging operation is just adding new commit with two parents (except for the case when there is no commits on the branch you are on, git will fast-forward then). In your case commit from branch B will be already merged on A and git would be aware about that.
In order to visualize that process I recommend to try your problem on [Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?NODEMO) web page.
List of commands that you need to execute:

```
 git checkout -b A
 git checkout -b B
 git commit
 git checkout -b C
 git commit
 git checkout A
 git commit
 git merge B
 git merge C
```